# Add transition to dynamic DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add transition to div element. Transition is applied successfully to first added div element. When I add more divs by clicking on `.container` then these new divs do not have this animation. **How can I add transitions to dynamic divs?**

Below is my code

```js
    var transition = 1;
    var x = 0;
    var left = 0;
    draw('white');
    var $rect = $('.rect');
    var $container = $('.container');
    var arr = ['red', 'green', 'black'];
    var count = 0;
    $('body').on('click', function () {
      draw(arr[count]);
      count++;
    });
    
    function init () {
      setInterval(onEachStep, 1000/60);
    }
    
    function onEachStep () {
      x += transition;
      left = left + transition;
      
      $rect.css('left', left + 'px');
      
      if (x > $container.outerWidth() - $rect.outerWidth()) {
        transition = -10;
      }
      
      if (x < 0) {
        transition = 1;
      }
    }
    
    function draw (color) {
      var rect = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'rect'
      });
      
      rect.css('background', color);
      
      rect.appendTo('.container');
    }
    
    init();
```

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 300px;
}

.rect {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store left, x and transition for each rectangle. Having the same left, x and transition for all of them would mean they all will be at the same position on any point in time.

```js
    draw('white');
    var $container = $('.container');
    var arr = ['red', 'green', 'black'];
    var count = 0;
    $('body').on('click', function () {
      draw(arr[count%arr.length]);
      count++;
    });
    
    function init () {
      setInterval(onEachStep, 1000/60);
    }
    
    function onEachStep () {
        $rect = $('.rect');
        for(var i = 0; i < $rect.length; i++) {
            var thisrect = $rect[i];
            thisrect.x += thisrect.transition;
            thisrect.left += thisrect.transition;
            
            $(thisrect).css('left', thisrect.left + 'px');
            if (thisrect.x > $container.outerWidth() - $(thisrect).outerWidth()) {
              thisrect.transition = -10;
            }
            
            if (thisrect.x < 0) {
              thisrect.transition = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    function draw (color) {
      var rect = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'rect'
      });
      
      rect.css('background', color);
      rect[0].x = 0;
      rect[0].left = 0;
      rect[0].transition = 1;
      rect.appendTo('.container');
    }
    
    init();
```

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 300px;
}

.rect {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: good one but querying `$('.rect')` 60 times per second is not recommended. you could move `$rect = $('.rect');` outside of `onEachStep` and call it only when needed.

Comment: that would definitely would NOT be the bottleneck. Calling $('.rect') 600 times in chrome will take 3ms. But it is true, you can save 0.3 ms for each second if you update $rect in the draw function.

Comment: @DinuSorin could you elaborate `thisrect` variable in your code? Where are you declaring it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the var declaration for it. I'm declaring it inside the for-loop of the onEachStep function (as is now indicated in the code). Basically, when you call a jQuery selector (like we do with .rect) you get returned a collection of all the dom elements that meet your selection criteria. The collection also contains all the jQuery functions (like .css etc). But, if you access an element at a position (same as with arrays) you get returned the DOM element at that position. So, in our example, $rect[$i] will return the i-th element in the $rect collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the `$rect` variable for that. find the code below

```js
    var transition = 1;
    var x = 0;
    var left = 0;
    draw('white');
    var $rect = $('.rect');
    var $container = $('.container');
    var arr = ['red', 'green', 'black'];
    var count = 0;
    $('body').on('click', function () {
      draw(arr[count]);
      count++;
      $rect = $('.rect');
    });
    
    function init () {
      setInterval(onEachStep, 1000/60);
    }
    
    function onEachStep () {
      x += transition;
      left = left + transition;
      
      $rect.css('left', left + 'px');
      
      if (x > $container.outerWidth() - $rect.outerWidth()) {
        transition = -10;
      }
      
      if (x < 0) {
        transition = 1;
      }
    }
    
    function draw (color) {
      var rect = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'rect'
      });
      
      rect.css('background', color);
      
      rect.appendTo('.container');
    }
    
    init();
```

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 300px;
}

.rect {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```